# Flush default cache

Tags: memcached, cakephp-2.0, couchbase

I am using a couchbase memcached bucket for my cakephp default cache. I would like to be able to flush the cache when I change the schema within my cakephp app. There is a [method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#Cache%3a%3aclear) to clear the cache however it is asking for arguments.

How do I use this method to clear / flush the cache?

Edit: my bootstrap contains the setup for the cache config

```
Cache::config('default', array(
    'engine' => 'Memcache',
    'prefix' => Inflector::slug(APP_DIR) . '_',
    'servers' => array(
            '127.0.0.1:11211' // localhost, default port 11211
        ), //[optional]
    'duration' => 7200,
    'serialize' => false,
    'persistent' => true, // [optional] set this to false for non-persistent connections
    'compress' => false,
    'probability' => 100 
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cache::clear(false, 'default'); // Default configuration, shortcut Cache::clear()
Cache::clear(false, '_cake_core_'); // General framework caching
Cache::clear(false, '_cake_model_'); // Cache for model and datasource caches
```

Comment: using the first option I get this error: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given

Comment: Warning (2): array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given [CORE/Cake/Cache/Engine/MemcacheEngine.php, line 212]

Comment: Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [CORE/Cake/Cache/Engine/MemcacheEngine.php, line 212]

Comment: Error at this line means you don't have any stored values.

Comment: I have added whats in my bootstrap